# Getting an undefined error when trying to set value of input node.js puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Basically, I'm trying to set the value of an input using node.js puppeteer. Here's the relevant code:

```
        //Enter email
        await page.evaluate(() => document.getElementsByName('emailOrPhone')[0].value = 'tester@gmail.com');
```

I've double checked that the actual selector is correct. As proof, here's a screenshot of me entering document.getElementsByName('emailOrPhone')[0].value into the console of the website, and getting a correct value:

[image]

But according to my console, I'm trying to set property 'value' of undefined. What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out

I was trying to set the value of the input before it had actually loaded onto the page. I believe this is called a "race condition". Anyway, after I called the method

```
    await page.waitForSelector('input[name="emailOrPhone"]');
```

and then tried to enter text into the input field, it worked

Answer (score -1):

Check the documentation of the puppeteer, [there is the method "type"](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.0.0/docs/api.md#elementhandletypetext-options)

You can use it like this:

```js
document.querySelector("[name=emailOrPhone]").type("test@test.test");
```

Comment: Tried this: await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector("[name=emailOrPhone]").type("test@test.test"));  ...  got error "cannot read property type of null"